# System.MissingMethodException IntPtr Tensorflow.Status.op_Implicit(Tensorflow.Status)''

Tags: c#, tensorflow, ml.net

I'm trying to load TensorFlow model(`SavedModel`) to ML.NET and create an estimator with ML.NET.

I am loading the model without errors, but `tensorFlowModel.ScoreTensorFlowModel` got Exception "System.MissingMethodException IntPtr Tensorflow.Status.op_Implicit(Tensorflow.Status)".

My code:

```
using Microsoft.ML;

var inputNodeName = "serving_default_dense_input";
var outputNodeName = "StatefulPartitionedCall_1";

var tensorFlowModel = mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(@"model"); //model directory contains saved_model.pb file
var pipeline = tensorFlowModel.ScoreTensorFlowModel(new[] { outputNodeName },new[] { inputNodeName }, addBatchDimensionInput: false);
```

Installed NuGet packages:

- `ML.NET`
- `SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist`
- `TensorFlow.NET`

These packages are updated to the latest version.

Comment: Are you just passing in a directory in the `LoadTensorFlowModel` method? I think it needs to be the pb file

Comment: @Jon `LoadTensorFlowModel` method passes.When incorrect inputNodeName is specified,got Exception 'Could not find operation "xyz" inside graph "grap-key-0/".'.So loading model seems to be succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same error a few times and it's always been a mismatch between ML.NET and TensorFlow versions. I noticed you've included `SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist` package and while there are probably tutorials that still mention using that later versions of ML.NET have a dependency on `TensorFlow.NET >= 0.11.8.1` that seems to include the necessary files so that's not necessary and a likely cause of your problem.

The other thing is while the dependency is >= 0.11.8.1 later versions of `TensorFlow.NET` can cause the the same problem as per this [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/4678) so also check you haven't updated to a later version of `TensorFlow.NET` and if you have try reverting back to 0.11.8.1.